# python-six errors

Tags: package-management, dependencies

I can not get any software to install, the installers will not even open. I can not upgrade to 17.04, same set of errors.

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit
7.7 GiB
Intel® Core™ i7-3840QM CPU @ 2.80GHz × 8
Quadro K3000M/PCIe/SSE2
306.6 GB

These are the errors:

```
larry@Dad-Precision-M6700:~/.config$ sudo apt-get install synaptic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-configobj : Depends: python-six but it is not going to be installed
 python-cryptography : Depends: python-six (>= 1.4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 python-html5lib : Depends: python-six but it is not going to be installed
 python-openssl : Depends: python-six but it is not going to be installed
 python-urllib3 : Depends: python-six but it is not going to be installed
 synaptic : Depends: libept1.5.0 but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: libgtk2-perl (>= 1:1.130) but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: rarian-compat but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Some more errors:

```
larry@Dad-Precision-M6700:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-click
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-configobj : Depends: python-six but it is not going to be installed
 python-cryptography : Depends: python-six (>= 1.4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 python-html5lib : Depends: python-six but it is not going to be installed
 python-openssl : Depends: python-six but it is not going to be installed
 python-urllib3 : Depends: python-six but it is not going to be installed
 python3-click : Depends: python3-colorama but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Perhaps the first thing to try is what it suggests: `sudo apt-get -f install`. What have you been trying to install which could be python related and how?

Comment: This is what I got.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to install `python-six` manually (and any other dependency it won't install automatically) and then try to install synaptic again.

Sometimes, apt does some weird things, especially after removing PPAs or things like this.

EDIT: Also, maybe try `sudo apt-get -f install` first (without any package names behind) as suggested by the comments and apt itself.